# Calling function within .each()

Tags: javascript, jquery

I would like to repeat the chained events starting at `.animate()` from inside itself (indicated by comment).  What is the correct way to write this?

```
$("div").each(function(i, e){  
  $(this).animate({ left: $(this).parent().width() }, d[i], "linear",
      function(){ $(this).css({left: -parseInt($(this).css("width")) })
      //would like to call function at this stage
   });
})
```

**This ended up working:**

```
   $("div").each( v = function(i, e){  
     $(this).animate({ left: $(this).parent().width() }, d[i], "linear",
         function(){ $(this).css({left: -parseInt($(this).css("width")) })
         v();
      });
   });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like this?

```
$("div").each(function(i, e){  
  $(this).animate({ left: $(this).parent().width() }, d[i], "linear",
      v = function(i){
            $(this).css({left: -parseInt($(this).css("width")) })
            if(i == null) v(1);
        });
})
```

Not sure I fully understood your goal...

Comment: This is just about what I needed to do, it helped me to complete the function correctly.  posted above.